# .net Maui distorted image on Imagebutton using svg

Tags: .net-maui

I'm trying to build some kind of toolbar (windows version) for my maui app.

I'm using .svg files for my images and it looks like this

[image: Original svg file]

But when I add it to my project and run it :(

[image]

And this is de XAML code

```
        <Grid x:Name="GrdOpciones">
            <ImageButton 
                Aspect="AspectFit" 
                Source="botondescartar.png"
                BackgroundColor="White" 
                HeightRequest="126"
                WidthRequest="240"
                CornerRadius="10"/>
        </Grid>
```

Height and width are exact size in pixels as the size on the svg designer. AspectFill or AspectFit make no sence I tryed both and same ugly result.

How Can I do to set image source to preserve the aspect of it?

EDIT 30Ag: Here U can download my svg

[Original svg](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuOVpatDsfSXl9g0igHynA-vBphN2w?e=eg5T7L)

Comment: **1)** "aspect" (aspect ratio) refers to whether it is stretched horizontally or vertically. Doesn't look stretched to me. Are you referring to "resolution"? The fact that it is very blurry, low resolution? Did you put `botondescartar.svg` into your project, with `Properties > Build Action` = `MauiImage`? **2)** Looks to me like Maui thinks the image will be used at a small size. Can you tell your image designer to scale it up 4x?  Save it as 504 x 960? OR specify a larger size in inches or centimeters? That should be identical as an SVG, but might convince Maui to make a larger .png.

Comment: **"Height and width are exact size in pixels as the size on the svg designer."** That's not sufficient. The dimensions in Maui are in DIPs. Each DIP is about 1/160 inch. A width of 240 DIPs is 1 1/2 inches. The svg designer has to output a file that says it is 1 1/2 inches wide (or larger). I think you need to specify its output size in inches, not pixels. Maui converts the .svg to .png when the app is built - it doesn't know the size you will display it; it only knows the size the .svg file says it is.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for try to help me. I'm going to do a test with larger svg

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Problem persists, something interesting, default button size assigned by MAUI is 64 * 34.

Comment: I have download a svg from the free svg website. And it shows clearly no matter what size I set the imagebutton as. So where did you get the svg file?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT svg made with adobe photoshop. Can U atthach your svg to this POST ?

Comment: I just download the svg from this [website](https://www.svgrepo.com/collection/hospital-bold-line-icons/).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT This is my svg https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuOVpatDsfSXl9g0igHynA-vBphN2w?e=eg5T7L

Comment: When I use your svg, it shows clearly on the android, but not on the windows. The svg I downloaded shows clearly both on the android and the windows.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT It means must build  images by platform ?

Comment: But the svg download from the website worked well on both android and windows.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT What can I do ? with my SVG files ?

Comment: You can report this to the maui on the github. It seems a bug. Or you can try to use another way to get the svg file.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Ok, I'm going to post it on github

Answer (score 1):

Maui will convert you image to a png at build time.  If the default base size the compiler picks is poor like your example, you can specify an alternate with the BaseSize attribute in your csproj file.  See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/images for more

Answer (score 0):

Although I had the same problem.
The problem was resolved by specifying a sufficiently large value in the BaseSize attribute.
Add the BaseSize attribute to MAUIImage by editing the csproj file directly.
Note that it must be a multiple of 8.
Please see the link provided by Jeremy Richards.